# How to Read NFC UID of Ios device from Android device

Tags: android, ios, kotlin, nfc

I want to read UID of Ios device from android device and vice versa , how can i do that with kotlin

Comment: On Android there is no point trying to read the UID because it is randomly generated and changes frequently as the UID in NFC is just needs to be Unique when multiple cards are presented to the same reader at the same time, therefore a random number works for this and also has security benefits that you cannot be tracked by it. I believe it is also random on iOS

Comment: @Andrew   I asked how can i read NFC id of ios device even it is changing or not , how can i read nfc of ios device from android device